# How to add an option to view all (*) in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a simple database with tables:
**Company**

```
'CompanyID', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, 'auto_increment'
'CompanyName', 'varchar(70)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'Type', 'enum(\'C\',\'M\',\'S\',\'A\')', 'NO', 'MUL', NULL, ''
'Country', 'varchar(60)', 'YES', 'MUL', NULL, ''
'Website', 'varchar(60)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'Email', 'varchar(60)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'Telephone', 'double unsigned', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'Maps_Link', 'varchar(60)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
```

**CompanyDetails**

```
'CompanyDetailsID', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, 'auto_increment'
'CompanyID', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'MUL', NULL, ''
'Type', 'enum(\'C\',\'M\',\'A\',\'S\')', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'Category', 'enum(\'MEP Consultant\',\'Lighting Designer\',\'Architect\',\'Interior Designer\',\'MEP Contractor\',\'Fitout Contractor\',\'Procurement Company\',\'Developer\',\'Outdoor-Architectural\',\'Indoor-Architectural\',\'Indoor-Decorative\',\'Outdoor-Decorative\',\'Lamps\',\'Drivers\',\'Control Systems\',\'Landscaping Consultant\',\'Landscaping Contractor\',\'Other\')', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'Comments', 'blob', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
```

and 3 more tables (**Contact, Continent, Product**)

I have created an app CompanyBrowser. I am trying to make a simple form with drop-down menus for:

- Type (from Company)
- Category (from Company Details)
- Country (from Company)

For each of these, I want the user to have the option to select all (*) in the drop-down menu.

Here is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns=[url(r'^$',views.Index,name='index'),
url(r'^(?P<company_type>[CMSA*])/$',views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
url(r'^(?P<company_type>[CMSA*])/(?P\<company_category>\w+)/$',views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
url(r'^(?P<company_type>[CMSA*])/(?P<company_category>\w+)/(?P<company_country>\w+)/$',views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
]<br>
```

Basically, I will be displaying according to url CompanyBrowser/company_type/company_category/company_country , where user can enter * i.e., all for any of the search field.

This is the ResultsView I have coded so far:

```
class ResultsView(generic.ListView):
    template_name='CompanyBrowser/results.html'
    context_object_name="results_of_company_type_query"
    def get_queryset(self):
        print(len(self.kwargs))
        if len(self.kwargs)==1:
            if self.kwargs['company_type']!="*":
                return Company.objects.filter(companytype=self.kwargs['company_type'])
            else return Company.objects.all()
        elif len(self.kwargs)==2:
            if self.kwargs["company_type"]=="M":
                if self.kwargs["company_category"]=="Indoor-Decorative":
                    return Company.objects.filter(companytype=self.kwargs['company_type'], companydetails__category=self.kwargs['company_category'])
```

What is an elegant way to do this instead of doing every combination of if elses? I think this could be easily done if there was an option to enter all within the filter query, perhaps?

Comment: I believe using contains in the filter query might help.

Comment: The code using contains is working well for me. Only problem I have is querying as per country as my country is a foreign key. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    for i in self.kwargs:
        if self.kwargs[i]=="*":
            self.kwargs[i]=""
    print(self.kwargs)
    print(len(self.kwargs))
    if len(self.kwargs)==1:
        queryset= Company.objects.filter(country__country__contains=self.kwargs['country'])
        print (queryset.query,"\n", len(queryset))
        return queryset
    elif len(self.kwargs)==2:
        queryset= Company.objects.filter(country__country__contains=self.kwargs['country'],
        companytype__contains=self.kwargs['company_type'])
        print (queryset.query,"\n", len(queryset))
        return queryset
    elif len(self.kwargs)==3:
        queryset= Company.objects.filter(country__country__contains=self.kwargs['company_country'], 
        companytype__contains=self.kwargs['company_type'],
        companydetails__category__contains=self.kwargs['company_category'],)
        print (queryset.query,"\n", len(queryset)   )
        return queryset
```

This works now. I used contains everywhere, so that my query returns with all objects if the search term is an empty string. Also, since country is a foreign keyed from the table Continent. I use **country__country__contains**.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to write it this way. In addition, you most probably want to use a separate form taking the GET request as a "filter".

```
class ResultsView(generic.ListView):
    template_name='CompanyBrowser/results.html'
    context_object_name="results_of_company_type_query"

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.kwargs.get('company_type') == 'M' and self.kwargs.get("company_category") == "Indoor-Decorative":
            return Company.objects.filter(companytype="M", companydetails__category="Indoor-Decorative")
        elif self.kwargs.get('company_type') != '*':
            return Company.objects.filter(companytype=self.kwargs['company_type'])
        else:
            return Company.objects.all()
```